# Rails read file Yomu gem - Psych::SyntaxError Exception - how to rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have Rails application that will give me number of pages from doc, docx and pdf if I upload it.

To get the number of pages, I use Yomu gem in following way in Document model:

```
  def update_information
      doc = Yomu.new(self.doc.url)
      self.num_of_pages = doc.metadata['xmpTPg:NPages']
      self.file_updated_at = doc.metadata['modified'] || doc.metadata['Creation-Date'] || Time.now
      self.file_created_at =  doc.metadata['Creation-Date'] || Time.now
   end
```

One of my documents is throwing exception:

```
*** Psych::SyntaxError Exception: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 23 column 15
```

and I can't figure it out how I could rescue it or avoid the problem without breaking the experience (it's a website).

By googling I tried this:

```
begin
  doc = Yomu.new(self.doc.url)
  self.num_of_pages = doc.metadata['xmpTPg:NPages']
  self.file_updated_at = doc.metadata['modified'] || doc.metadata['Creation-Date'] || Time.now
  self.file_created_at =  doc.metadata['Creation-Date'] || Time.now
rescue Psych::SyntaxError, StandardError => e
  print e
end
```

But it didn't work and it's still throwing the error and breaking the flow.

Any suggestion how to fix?